# Go build crashes with "lfstackPack redeclared in this block" on windows

Tags: windows, go

I've done some golang on unix in the past, but I just tried to install it on windows and I can't get `go build` to work.

When I try to compile any go source code, it crashes with:

```
# runtime
C:\Go\src\runtime\lfstack_amd64.go:16: lfstackPack redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at C:\Go\src\runtime\lfstack_64bit.go:37
C:\Go\src\runtime\lfstack_amd64.go:20: lfstackUnpack redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at C:\Go\src\runtime\lfstack_64bit.go:41
C:\Go\src\runtime\os_windows.go:14: _NSIG redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at C:\Go\src\runtime\os2_windows.go:18
C:\Go\src\runtime\os_windows.go:104: _AddVectoredExceptionHandler redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at C:\Go\src\runtime\os1_windows.go:92
C:\Go\src\runtime\os_windows.go:104: _CloseHandle redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at C:\Go\src\runtime\os1_windows.go:92
C:\Go\src\runtime\os_windows.go:104: _CreateEventA redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at C:\Go\src\runtime\os1_windows.go:92
C:\Go\src\runtime\os_windows.go:104: _CreateIoCompletionPort redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at C:\Go\src\runtime\os1_windows.go:92
C:\Go\src\runtime\os_windows.go:104: _CreateThread redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at C:\Go\src\runtime\os1_windows.go:92
C:\Go\src\runtime\os_windows.go:104: _CreateWaitableTimerA redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at C:\Go\src\runtime\os1_windows.go:92
C:\Go\src\runtime\os_windows.go:104: _CryptAcquireContextW redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at C:\Go\src\runtime\os1_windows.go:92
C:\Go\src\runtime\os_windows.go:104: too many errors
```

Comment: You have files from multiple versions of Go in your source tree. Either clean your git tree, or delete the source and unpack the correct tarball.

Comment: @JimB I have tried deleting the installation and rerunning the installer, but to no avail.

Comment: Are you sure you completely deleted the Go directory? For example, the files `lfstack_amd64.go`, `os1_windows.go` and `os2_windows.go` don't exist in the current source.

Comment: @JimB Turned out the installer wasn't working right. Thanks for the help